# what is the logic of the following Recursion code

Tags: c, recursion

can you please explain the functioning of the following code

```
int main()
{
    func1(10, 18);
    return 0;
}
func1(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return;
    func1(a, b - 1);
    printf("%d ", b);
}
```

the following code gives
18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10

Comment: The code you've posted emits a warning and it invokes Undefined Behavior as you don't return an `int` from `func1`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seeks bad code explained - no use to future SO visitors.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @Neerav The output does not correspond to the program logic. It sshould be 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

Answer (score 2):

I'll be explaining the logic in the below program as your program, when compiling, emits a warning because you do not return an `int` from a function designed to return an `int`.

## Program:

```
int main()
{
    func1(10, 18);
    return 0;
}

void func1(int a, int b)
{
    if(a > b)
        return;

    func1(a, b - 1);

    printf("%d ", b);
}
```

## Explanation:

1. First `func1` is called from `main` with arguments 10 and 18 respectively:

   ```
   func1(10, 18);
   ```
2. The condition `if(a > b)` is false as `a` (currently 10) is not less than `b` (currently 18)
3. Second `func1` is called from `func1` with arguments 10 and 17 respectively:

   ```
   func1(a, b - 1);
   ```
4. The condition `if(a > b)` is false as `a` (currently 10) is not less than `b` (currently 17)
5. Third `func1` is called from `func1` with arguments 10 and 16 respectively:

   ```
   func1(a, b - 1);
   ```
6. The condition `if(a > b)` is false as `a` (currently 10) is not less than `b` (currently 16)
7. Fourth `func1` is called from `func1` with arguments 10 and 15 respectively:

   ```
   func1(a, b - 1);
   ```
8. The condition `if(a > b)` is false as `a` (currently 10) is not less than `b` (currently 15)
9. Fifth `func1` is called from `func1` with arguments 10 and 14 respectively:

   ```
   func1(a, b - 1);
   ```
10. The condition `if(a > b)` is false as `a` (currently 10) is not less than `b` (currently 14)
11. Sixth `func1` is called from `func1` with arguments 10 and 13 respectively:

    ```
    func1(a, b - 1);
    ```
12. The condition `if(a > b)` is false as `a` (currently 10) is not less than `b` (currently 13)
13. Seventh `func1` is called from `func1` with arguments 10 and 12 respectively:

    ```
    func1(a, b - 1);
    ```
14. The condition `if(a > b)` is false as `a` (currently 10) is not less than `b` (currently 12)
15. Eighth `func1` is called from `func1` with arguments 10 and 11 respectively:

    ```
    func1(a, b - 1);
    ```
16. The condition `if(a > b)` is false as `a` (currently 10) is not less than `b` (currently 11)
17. Nineth `func1` is called from `func1` with arguments 10 and 10 respectively:

    ```
    func1(a, b - 1);
    ```
18. The condition `if(a > b)` is false as `a` (currently 10) is not less than `b` (currently 10)
19. Tenth `func1` is called from `func1` with arguments 10 and 9 respectively:

    ```
    func1(a, b - 1);
    ```
20. The condition `if(a > b)` *is true* as `a` (currently 10) is less than `b` (currently 9). Thus, the `return` statement executes and the execution of the Tenth `func1` gets completed.
21. The ninth `func1` starts from the spot where it has stopped (`func1(a, b - 1);`) and prints **10** (since the value of `b` is 10, currently) and ends execution.
22. The eighth `func1` starts from the spot where it has stopped (`func1(a, b - 1);`) and prints **11** (since the value of `b` is 11, currently) and ends execution.
23. The seventh `func1` starts from the spot where it has stopped (`func1(a, b - 1);`) and prints **12** (since the value of `b` is 12, currently) and ends execution.
24. The sixth `func1` starts from the spot where it has stopped (`func1(a, b - 1);`) and prints **13** (since the value of `b` is 13, currently) and ends execution.
25. The fifth `func1` starts from the spot where it has stopped (`func1(a, b - 1);`) and prints **14** (since the value of `b` is 14, currently) and ends execution.
26. The fourth `func1` starts from the spot where it has stopped (`func1(a, b - 1);`) and prints **15** (since the value of `b` is 15, currently) and ends execution.
27. The third `func1` starts from the spot where it has stopped (`func1(a, b - 1);`) and prints **16** (since the value of `b` is 16, currently) and ends execution.
28. The second `func1` starts from the spot where it has stopped (`func1(a, b - 1);`) and prints **17** (since the value of `b` is 17, currently) and ends execution.
29. The first `func1` starts from the spot where it has stopped (`func1(a, b - 1);`) and prints **18** (since the value of `b` is 18, currently) and ends execution.
30. Execution returns to `main` and `return 0;` executes, terminating the program.

Comment: What patience would be taken to write that answer. Nice one Sir !!